# Accept all cookies automatically in Selenium Chrome driver

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, selenium-chromedriver

I am using [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/) with [Chrome web driver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) in python.
I would like to automatically accept all cookies when opening any website and get rid of the cookie notification like the following:

[image]

Is there any option in Chrome driver that allows to do that?

Comment: I don't think that this is anything chromedriver can do directly as the cookie banners are implemented differently on every site and not something browser related. You will likely need to accept them by clicking the buttons, but this will be specific to every site you visit

Answer (score -1):

```
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
```

please use this